# Removing default favicon from WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, favicon

How can I remove the default favicon link from the WordPress theme? I know I can replace the favicon but I am looking for using the remove_action or something like that which I can place in my functions.php.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just remove this line in `header.php`:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.example.com/favicon.png" />
```

It isn't loaded automatically, so you can't remove it using a `filter`/`remove_action`.

Comment: I recommend adding favicon.ico to the root, to avoid load unneeded favicon when files requested.

Answer (score 12):

I have used the following filter in the theme `functions.php` file to remove the original WordPress favicon from being output in the `wp_head()` function.

```
add_filter( 'get_site_icon_url', '__return_false' );
```

This filter removes the URL of the chosen image to be a favicon, so it returns false when WordPress checks for the URL to display it.

There is also an option to create a function that displays the favicon on the following actions:

- `wp_head`
- `admin_head`
- `wp_head`

using the following way:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'prefix_favicon', 100 );
add_action( 'admin_head', 'prefix_favicon', 100 );
function prefix_favicon() {
    //code of the favicon logic
    ?>
        <link rel="icon" href="LINK TO FAVICON">
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Works great, thank you. The `wp_head` action is being specified twice though.

Answer (score 6):

This question seems quiet old, but new with WordPress 5.4 (03/2020) is a default WP-Favicon, which can be very annoying if you don´t want any. It is also activated for every updated website from version 5.4. Sure, you can change it with the customizer in the normal way, but can´t delete it or need to hack around with transparent images or sth. like that.

> Try this little function to remove the favicon (from WP 5.4!) as if it
> had never been there.

```
add_action( 'do_faviconico', 'magic_favicon_remover');
function magic_favicon_remover() {
    exit;
}
```

**For more informations, have a look at this:**

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_faviconico/

Answer (score 1):

If a physical /favicon.ico file exists, do nothing and let the server handle the request.
for example [www.domain.com/favicon.ico](http://www.domain.com/favicon.ico)

[reference](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/02/19/enhancements-to-favicon-handling-in-wordpress-5-4/)